# Facebook sso integration not working

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

Am looking proper fb sso.When i searched i got guidance from hackbook.but Fb sso sometimes working smetimetime its not working what may be the cause.i didnt get any error.I added following as well

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    authenticatedFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your internet connection dropping out?  If it does and you are trying to authorize everytime rather than checking the existing token then lack of internet connection would cause it to fail.  This is just a guess though as I can not see your code and cannot see any stack trace in your question.

Comment: if my internet connection is dropping,when i run foursquare in android also face same problem in FB sso right..Foursquare is working fine

Comment: am not getting any error...fb loading for sometime then again came back to login screen

Comment: Sometime working fine..smetime may nt wrking..wen its nt wrking i try check other sso implemented app like foursqurae it was wrking with foursquare

Comment: As I said if you do it correctly you will check the access token and just check if its still valid, this would allow you to still use SSO when you don;t have an internet connection, however, if you are authorizing every time it will require internet connection.  Other applications are checking to see if the access token is still valid.

Comment: SessionStore.restore(Utility.mFacebook, this);
         SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new FbAPIsAuthListener());
         SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new FbAPIsLogoutListener());
         mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
         String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
         long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
         if(access_token != null) {
          Utility.mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
         }
         if(expires != 0) {
          Utility.mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
         }